# Can we display two attributes in one ggplot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Reading about plots for ordinal data I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56322/graph-for-relationship-between-two-ordinal-variables) plot:

[image: Plot]

I find the legend redundant since a small frequency of 10, for instance, is always a small sqaure *and* a light square, and so on. Thus, I would like to create a plot with a legend like this (paint solution):

[image: Desired plot]

Code to recreate the plot

```
# DATA
importance <- rep(1:5, times = c(30, 42, 75, 93, 60))
often <- c(rep(1:5, times = c(15, 07, 04, 03, 01)), #n=30, importance 1
           rep(1:5, times = c(10, 14, 12, 03, 03)), #n=42, importance 2
           rep(1:5, times = c(12, 23, 20, 13, 07)), #n=75, importance 3
           rep(1:5, times = c(16, 14, 20, 30, 13)), #n=93, importance 4
           rep(1:5, times = c(12, 06, 11, 17, 14))) #n=60, importance 5
running.df <- data.frame(importance, often)
runningcounts.df <- as.data.frame(table(importance, often))

# PLOT
theme_nogrid <- function (base_size = 12, base_family = "") {
  theme_bw(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace% 
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank())   
}

ggplot(runningcounts.df, aes(importance, often)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Freq, color = Freq, stat = "identity", position = "identity"), shape = 15) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3,15)) + 
  scale_color_gradient(low = "white", high = "black") +
  theme_nogrid()
```

Comment: Hi. Your code does not include `runningcount.df`, did you forgot to add something?

Comment: @Maël Added to question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using `guides`, adding `guides(color = guide_legend(), size = guide_legend())` line to your code.

```
ggplot(runningcounts.df, aes(importance, often)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Freq, color = Freq, stat = "identity", position = "identity"), shape = 15) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3,15)) + 
  scale_color_gradient(low = "white", high = "black") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(), size = guide_legend()) +
  theme_nogrid()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick fix, this should work

```
# PLOT
theme_nogrid <- function (base_size = 12, base_family = "") {
  theme_bw(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace% 
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank())   
}

ggplot(runningcounts.df, aes(importance, often)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Freq, color = Freq, stat = "identity", position = "identity"), shape = 15) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3,15)) + 
  scale_color_gradient(low = "white", high = "black") +
  theme_nogrid()+
  guides( colour = guide_legend()) #added guides()
```

[image]

Comment: It is similiar to the answer of Park. But as your answer suggests the is no need to specify `  guides(color = guide_legend(), size = guide_legend()) +` as in Parks answer. I`ll need to learn more about guides. Thanks (+1)